# Can't sculpt in 2.93

Tags: sculpting

I've been sculpting on 2.91 for over 6 months and just downloaded 2.93 recently. In sculpt mode, left click always move the object no matter which brush I'm on. I still have 2.91 installed and sculpt mode works fine there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure its because you need to change the "Select with mouse button" setting. To change it, go to:
Edit > Preferences > Keymap > Select with mouse button > (Change it to) Right

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help